# python 3.4 lambda and revrse her how

Tags: python

I have question about python 3.4.

let's say I do:

```
inches_to_meters =lambda x: x*0.0254
inches_to_feets =lambda x: x*(1/12)
miles_to_feets =lambda x: x*5280
```

I want to know how to calculate the opposite function, only with lambda how can I do it?

For example:

```
feets_to_inches = opposite(inches_to_feets)
```

or for more example I want composition  with lambda only:

```
miles_to_inches = composition(feets_to_inches, miles_to_feets)
```

tnx for the help

Comment: The opposite i not possible. You can not reverse a lambda-expression, since that is an undecidable problem.

Comment: so how can I do this task?

Comment: well as said before, it is not possible. This is one of the fundamentals of computability theory https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undecidable_problem

Comment: Some functions are fundamentally irreversible. For example, if you multiply something by 0, you will always get 0. If you reverse that, how are you meant to know what the input was?

Comment: so how I can do feets_to_inches(10)with use this lamda?

Comment: @Shakedast: do you know what *fundamentally impossible* means? It means that even within 100'000 years nobody can ever come up with a way to reverse a function (or lambda expression) in general. Some functions can be reversed, but a generic way to solve it is *fundamentally* impossible. It has nothing to do with computers not being fast enough, or memory requirements, even if we would have access to super quantum computers and have an unlimited amount of memory it is still not possible.

Comment: `feet_to_inches = lambda x: x * 12`

Comment: this is somewhat surreal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The task is specifically limited to converting distances using the specified lambdas as the base and using an opposite and composition lambdas for the rest.

Since the conversion of these units is rather simple, you can get the conversion factor by dividing by 1 first. Basically:

```
opposite = lambda f: lambda x: x/f(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Willem Van Onsem says, you cannot automatically define the inverse of a function. You can, however, compute the appropriate conversion factor and pass that to a converter-making function.

```
def make_converter(factor):
    def _(x):
        return x * factor
    return _

inches_in_feet = 12

feet_to_inches = make_converter(inches_in_feet)
inches_to_feet = make_converter(1/inches_in_feet)
```

Composition, however, is trivial (assuming the output of the first function
is the expected input of the second):

```
def composition(f, g):
    return lambda x: f(g(x))
```